# Tangent to a function in 2 points

Tags: calculus

I have a function that looks like this- the function is a parametric function $x=x(t) y=y(t)$ [image]

And I need to find the line tangent to it.
Would it be right to do $(y(t2)-y(t1))/(x(t2)-x(t1))=a$

$(dy(t)/dx(t))|_t1=a$
and
$(dy(t)/dx(t))|_t2=a$ 
so it will be 3 equations in 3 variables?

$dy/dx= (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$
thanks

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good method to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(y(t2)-y(t1))/(x(t2)-x(t1))=a$

$(dy(t)/dx(t))|_t1=a$
and
$(dy(t)/dx(t))|_t2=a$ 
so it will be 3 equations in 3 variables

$dy/dx= (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$